# Error fetching the json from forbes website in R using jsonlite

Tags: r, jsonlite

Here is my code:

```
forbesList<-fromJSON('https://www.forbes.com/ajax/list/data?year=2018&uri=powerful-brands&type=organization')
```

Error Details:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
           (!doctype html) (html lang="en")
(right here) ------^
```

Please help me out, i tried in many ways to resolve this issue, but failed. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `fromJSON` needs to be actual JSON text, not a URL pointing to some JSON text.  Try downloading the JSON content first, then make your call to `fromJSON`:

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://www.forbes.com/ajax/list/data?year=2018&uri=powerful-brands&type=organization"
req <- GET(url)
stop_for_status(req)
json <- content(req, "text")
forbesList <- fromJSON(json)
```

I have verified [here](http://json.parser.online.fr) that the JSON content from your URL parses correctly, so I don't think this should be a problem.

Comment: I am getting the below error after executing the 'getURLContent(url)':
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Comment: @goutham_mi3 This is an SSL error of some kind.  Try my updated answer using the `curl` library instead.

Comment: Still the same issue. 
Warning message:
In readLines(con) :
  incomplete final line found on 'https://www.forbes.com/ajax/list/data?year=2018&uri=powerful-brands&type=organization'

For code: forbesList <-fromJSON(json)
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       **<!doctype html> <html lang="en"
                     (right here) ------^**

Comment: What is your output from `readLines`?  Does it look like JSON?

Comment: Its a tab based html content. > json
 [1] "<!doctype html>"                                                                                               
 [2] "<html lang=\"en\">"                                                                                                                                          
 [3] "\t<head>"                                                                                                                                                     
 [4] "\t\t<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Language\" content=\"en_US\">"  . But it doesnt contain any required data.

Comment: @goutham_mi3 Try using `httr`.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Issue not resolved. The 'json' object in your code above is returning xml_document. So getting the below error for code: forbesList<-fromJSON(json)
Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.

Comment: Can you try using `json <- content(req, "text")` ?

Comment: Still lexical error issue at 'forbesList' object. Please email me if you have any further suggestions. Thanks.